# missing ptr = NULL in destructor causing error, works fine with ptr set to NULL. Why?

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

If i comment the line `arr = 0;` in destructor definition, the program terminates with an error. If i uncomment that line i.e., `arr` is set to `0`, then the program executes without any error. Why is it so as there is no need of setting a pointer to NULL. The pointer itself is destroyed after the execution of destructor.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Below is my code.

Array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H
class Array
{
    int* arr;
    int size;
public:
    Array(int size = 10);
    Array(const Array& arr);
    ~Array();
    void display () const;
};
#endif
```

Array.cpp

```
#include "Array.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Array::Array(int size)
{
    arr = new int[size];
    this->size = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
}

Array::Array(const Array& a)
{
    arr = new int[a.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
        arr[i] = a.arr[i];
    size = a.size;
}

Array::~Array()
{
    delete[] arr;
    arr = 0;
}

void Array::display() const
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Array arr(4);
    Array a1 = arr;
    a1.display();
    arr.~Array();
    a1.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling the destructor here:

```
arr.~Array();
```

When `arr` goes out of scope, the destructor is called a second time. That leads to undefined behaviour when `delete[]` is called on the pointer data member `arr`. When you set that to `0`, you side-step the problem, but the fact remains that you shouldn't be invoking the destructor like that.

Here's an example showing how the lifetime of an automatic storage object is bound to its scope:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo destructor\n";
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << in main()\n";

  {
    Foo f;
  }  // f gets destroyed here

  std::cout << "Exiting main()\n";
};
```

Comment: When the destructor is called second time? How a destructor is being called again on an already destroyed object that no more exists.

Comment: @UmarShabbir the object exists until `main` is exited. This is when the destructor gets automatically called.

Comment: @UmarShabbir in c++ the compiler ensures that every object on the stack will be automatically destroyed at the end of the scope it is defined in. While you can destroy the object yourself you have to ensure to create a new object at the same place (placement new) before the compiler generated code calls the destructor on it a second time. Generally you wont find explicit destructor calls or placement new outside of container classes (std::vector) and unless you have a very good reason you should avoid calling them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly call destructors.
They will execute once the program terminates.
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/86-destructors/
look at the article under the heading constructor and destructor timing

The destructors are written to deallocate the memory assigned to pointers. Otherwise the pointer is deleted but its memory remains dangling.
When the program terminates, all the variables will be lost from the memory, all resources will be deallocated, and during that time the destructor will execute itself.

Comment: In this case, the destructor is called when the scope of `main` is left, not at program termination.